# Changing the defaut star in radio buttons in PDF forms

Tags: hyperref, forms

In PDF forms, is there any way to change the default star in radio buttons to a solid circle?

Comment: You mean PDF forms created using the `hyperref` package? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates this, so other people see what you are using and can modify it to contain the solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the option `radiosymbol=<value>`, where you can choose from the available [`pifont`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont) elements (or something different):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\def\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu{12pt}%
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionA,radio]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionB,radio,radiosymbol=]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionC,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionD,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{109}]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionE,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{96}]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

If you're interested in a reversed selection (placing the check box first, followed by the description), this a way to do it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\def\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu{12pt}%
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionA,radio]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionA,radio]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionA,radio]{\mbox{}}\null Option3

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionB,radio,radiosymbol=]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionB,radio,radiosymbol=]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionB,radio,radiosymbol=]{\mbox{}}\null Option3

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionC,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionC,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionC,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{\mbox{}}\null Option3

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionD,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{109}]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionD,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{109}]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionD,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{109}]{\mbox{}}\null Option3

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionE,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{96}]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionE,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{96}]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionE,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{96}]{\mbox{}}\null Option3
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

For displaying the options on separate lines, just insert a paragraph break `\par` at the end of each line.

Here is the [`pifont` quick reference guide](http://willbenton.com/wb-images/pifont.pdf):

[image]

Comment: @Werner deleting `\mbox{}`and `\medskip` results same output.

Comment: @Werner why there is no short answer for **reversed selection** instead of repeating same text?

Comment: @Werner the round button not come. [image](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/17/10/03/59d3b6f353103.png)