# Cannot select radio elements, even output is not similiar

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, forms

Referring to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39545/60311) my output first doesn't look similiar and I also can't click on the elements. I've used the exact same code there. Has anyone an idea why this happens? His first example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\def\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu{12pt}%
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionA,radio]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionB,radio,radiosymbol=]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionC,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionD,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{109}]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionE,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{96}]{}{Option1,Option2,Option3}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

His output:

[image]

My output:

[image]

His second example does lead to another issue: Radio's should be grouped by name, this seems not to happen on me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\def\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu{12pt}%
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionA,radio]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionA,radio]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionA,radio]{\mbox{}}\null Option3

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionB,radio,radiosymbol=]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionB,radio,radiosymbol=]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionB,radio,radiosymbol=]{\mbox{}}\null Option3

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionC,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionC,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionC,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{\mbox{}}\null Option3

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionD,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{109}]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionD,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{109}]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionD,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{109}]{\mbox{}}\null Option3

\medskip

\ChoiceMenu[name=optionE,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{96}]{\mbox{}}\null Option1
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionE,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{96}]{\mbox{}}\null Option2
\ChoiceMenu[name=optionE,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{96}]{\mbox{}}\null Option3
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

His output:

[image]

My output:

[image]

My System: Lubuntu x64 12.04 LTS

```
pdftex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.50
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5
```

I have no idea where that issue comes from and how to fix it.

Comment: I can't confirm your issue (Linux x64, Texlive 2014, hyperref version [2012/11/06 v6.83m), the output is exactly as 'his version'. Sorry, but we need more information

Comment: I can confirm your issue (Fedora 19 x64, TeXLive 2014, hyperref v6.83m) using `pdflatex`. If I used `xelatex` the giant open quotes disappear but there are still no radio boxes for the second and third options. I've tried viewing the pdf with `okular` and `evince` but the result's the same. I sent a copy of the pdf to my son and it viewed correctly on Adobe Reader running on his Windows laptop. I don't know what's causing it.

Comment: I can confirm this issue, too (Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, TeXLive 2013, 2012/11/06 v6.83m, `pdflatex`). The ancient Adobe Reader 9.5.5 for Linux shows it correctly, Okular and Evince do not.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20179/16684

Comment: This seems to be a bug in hyperref https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/3