# hyperref package ChoiceMenu results weird symbol?

Tags: forms

My [questionaire.tex](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25658930/) is as follows -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
We want to buildup a statistical model to predict tution fees of students. We will use these information to build up the model. Your privacy must be ensured. Please help us for developing the model by giving your inFormation mentioning below-\\\\

\TextField[name=name]{Name:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=year]{Year:}{1st,2nd,3rd,4th,MS}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=university]{University:}{BUET,DMC,DU,JNU,JU}\\\\
  \TextField[name=dept.]{Department:}  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=section]{Section:}{Science,Arts,Comerce}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=hsscsection]{HSSC Section:}{Science,Arts,Comerce}\\\\
  \TextField[name=hsscCollege]{HSSC College:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=hall]{Hall:}\ChoiceMenu[name=hall]{}{mess,Basha}\\\\
  \TextField[name=homedistict]{Home Distict:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=foccupation]{Father's occupation:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=moccupation]{Mother's occupation:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=familymembers]{Family members:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=earningmembers]{No of earning members:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=birthposition]{Birth Position:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=texperi]{no,1y,2y,3y,4y,4up}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=scholarship]{Getting scholarship per month:}{0.00,1-2,2.1-3.0,3.1-4.0,4.1-5.0,5up}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=takingmoneyhome]{Getting money per month from home:}{0.00,1-2,2.1-3.0,3.1-4.0,4.1-5.0,5up}\\\\
  \TextField[name=tourcount]{Number of tour per year:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=meal]{From where taking meal:}{Hall dyning/mess, Hall canteen, hotel,Basha}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=GF]{Having GF?}{yes,no}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=smoker]{Smoker?}{yes,no}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=readd]{Having readdmission?}{yes,no}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[name=result]{Result:}{<2.5,<3.00,<3.5,<4.00}\\\\

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

And the output of this code looks like as bellow in evince.

[image]
[image]

[questionaire.log file here.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25659091/)

The `Year` choicemenu's choices shows in one line(I like), but some(`scholarship, taking meal etc.`) in vertical line(I don't like). And the one line choices are not checkable and their symbols are weird.

How can I fix the problem?
If the check button is appeared before the option then the answer is most welcomed(optional requirement). i.e. `Year: [button1]1st year [button2]2nd year` instead of `1st year[button1] 2nd year[option2]`

Comment: I can't replicate your incorrect output. Can you also include your `.log`?

Comment: @Werner [questionaire.log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25659091/)

Comment: It varies according to pdf viewer see http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/eforms.shtml for some examples.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195154/cannot-select-radio-elements-even-output-is-not-similiar